# What can I do if I mix up PCG.se and FOS.se icons?

Tags: support, design, hot-questions, beta-sites, favicon

I really like to see the Hot P(P)CG Network Questions, and I know how to identify them with its icon [image]. Unfortunately, I sometimes click on a "wrong" link that bring me to an Open Source question, which have this icon: [image].

Somehow, although I'm a young developer with "good eyes", I mix up the P with the F and the C with the O (and my brain probably conclude that if the P and the C are good, the G has to be good too...).

It may be stupid, but this is the second time in a month that it happened to me, and I can't count the number of times I didn't actually click on the link but wanted to, and my brain had to say "No, stupid! You see well that it's FOS and not PCG that you see".

**So, can I do something to not mix up those icons?**

PS:

- According to [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278782/how-is-an-icon-for-a-site-created-or-added-to-that-site), the "not in beta any more" sites are supposed to have a designed icon, which was discussed [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/788/our-favicon-is-ugly-and-asymmetric-lets-fix-it) (but this is an old post, and I'm not a participant of the PPCG community so they maybe like their icon and don't want it to change...).
- [This discussion](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53/why-is-the-site-icon-fos-and-should-it-be-changed) speaks about the "F" in the "FOS" icon.

Comment: What can I do if I mix up Spanish.se and EarthScience.se icons?

Comment: All beta site icons are very similar, nothing SE can do about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some possible solutions:

- As you mentioned, the problem will eventually be solved by PPCG getting a full-blown design. According to [this list](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched), it's likely it will be one of the first they'll do when they have time, but it could take a while since there haven't been any designs for a long time.
- Use a custom CSS stylesheet to hide/modify `div.favicon-opensource`. How this works exactly depends on your browser, but the result looks like this:

[image]

- Write a userscript to hide/modify the Open Source favicon.

Comment: I thought of your second point and will probably do it !